# When adding a reference and then an appendix section in LaTeX, compiling it places some (but not all) items from the appendix before references

Tags: latex

I want to place two graphs in the appendix of my LaTeX document after the reference section, here's what I did :

```
\section*{Conclusion}

[...]


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\section*{Appendix}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{Images/Figure1.jpg}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{Images/Figure2.jpg}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't mess up the format but puts every section one after the other, while I'd like to have page breaks between conclusion and references and between references and Appendix. Putting either will make some elements of the Appendix appear before the section.

I used \pagebreak to skip to the next page if that can help.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre] that we can compile without having access to external files like `./Tables/Table2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your figures do not have any placement specifiers. Using these, you should be able to place the figures as intended, and manage the page breaks independently. Probably using `h!` or `h!t` will do the trick:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics{Images/Figure1.jpg}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

If that doesn't help, you can use `[H]` of package `float` to force the figure to exactly that position in the text.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed my issue with graphs placement. do you know why my table 2 is misplaced and why the \pagebreak do not work ?

Comment: You don't mention a table 2. Which do you mean? Also, try \newpage instead of \pagebreak.

Comment: Yes sorry I got mixed up with another question. I tried both pagebreak and newpage, It did not make a change

Comment: The code you posted in the other answer does not contain the table itself, so hard to say. If you are using the `table`enviroment - that has the positioning specifiers as well - use [h!] again. You can also move the table backward in your code to see if it is arranged better.